# Inverse Laplace transformation using reside method of transfer function that contains time delay

Tags: laplace-transform, residue-calculus

I'm having a problem trying to inverse laplace transform the following equation

$$
  h_0 = K_p * \frac{1 - T s}{1 + T s} e ^ { - \tau s}
$$

I've tried to solve this equation using the residue method and got the following.

$$
  y(t) = 2 K_p  e ^ {- \tau s} e ^ {-t/T}
$$

$$
  y(t) = 2 K_p e ^ {\frac{\tau}{T}} e ^ {-t/T}
$$

And that is clearly wrong.

Is it so that you can't use the residue method on functions that contains time delay, or is it possible to do a "work around" or something to get to the right answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First do polynomial division to simplify the fraction:

$$\frac{1-Ts}{1+Ts}=-1+\frac{2}{1+Ts}$$

Now expand $h_0$:

$$h_0=-K_pe^{-\tau{s}}+2K_p\frac{1}{Ts+1}e^{-\tau{s}}$$

Recall the time-domain shift property:

$$\scr{L}(f(t-\tau))=f(s)e^{-\tau{s}}$$

$$\scr{L}^{-1}h_0=-k_p\delta{(t-\tau)}+2k_p g(t-\tau)$$

Where $g(t)=\scr{L}^{-1}\frac{1}{ts+1}$.

To take the inverse Laplace transform of this term, recall the frequency domain shift property:

$$\scr{L}^{-1}f(s-a)=f(t)e^{at}$$

$$\frac{1}{Ts+1}=\frac{1}{T(s+\frac{1}{T})}=\frac{1}{T}\frac{1}{s+\frac{1}{T}}$$
Therefore the inverse Laplace transform is:

$$\frac{1}{T}e^{-\frac{t}{T}}$$

Finally, putting all of it together, the full inverse Laplace transform of the original expression is:

$$-K_p\delta(t-\tau)+\frac{2K_p}{T}e^{-\frac{t-\tau}{T}}$$

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! But is functions with time delay impossible to solve using the residue method? Is that a limitation of the residue method?

Comment: @sighol No, the residue method wouldn't work because the rational function (that is, the $\frac{1-Ts}{1+Ts}$) is too simple to be reduced by it. You can't factor the denominator, so the residue method wouldn't simplify it any further than it already is. But that's not because of the time shift.